# How to show category name in category carousels for home page?

Tags: category, extensions, magento-1

I am using [pcarousel](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-category-product-carousel.html) extension in AccessShop theme for my store.

I am going to use multiple carousels for categories on homepage.

How to show category name in category carousels for home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$category_id = 5;
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$category_name = $_category->getName();
```

`Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)` -> load category by id so that all attribute of category value you can get.
`$category_name = $_category->getName();` -> Here with get method you get name of category.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation about your code?

Comment: Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) -> load category by id so that all attribute of category value you can get.

$category_name = $_category->getName(); -> Here with get method you get name of category.

Comment: Thanks @Prashant Barot, It worked!

I used it like :

`<?php $cruid = $this->getPcarouselId(); 
    $crudata = Mage::getModel('pcarousel/pcarousel')->load($cruid)->getData();
    $categoryid = $crudata['categories'];

    //Category Name
 $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryid);
 $category_name = $_category->getName();
    
?>`